# How to generate a random variable from an enum that has cases with arguments in Swift?

Tags: swift

Given the following enum:

```
enum GameLevel {
    case Level(Int)
    case TutorialLevel, BossLevel
}
```

How to generate a random variable of type `GameLevel` in Swift?

Comment: Huh? When you call what, you expect what?

Comment: let's say `let a:gameLevel = //what to put here to get a random case?`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I updated your enum as per Apple standards (Capital letter to start a Type, and no abbreviations.

```
enum GameLevel {
    case Level(Int)
    case TutorialLevel, BossLevel
}
```

First, how to create a constant or variable with a value for level.

```
let level = GameLevel.Level(1)
```

Next, for a random value to level use [`arc4random_uniform`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man3/arc4random_uniform.3.html):

```
let maxGameLevel: UInt32 = 10
let randomGameLevel: Int = Int(arc4random_uniform(maxGameLevel))
let level = GameLevel.Level(randomGameLevel)
```

Of course, this can be put into a function:

```
func RandomGameLevel() -> GameLevel {
    let maxGameLevel: UInt32 = 10
    return .Level(Int(arc4random_uniform(maxGameLevel)))
}

let level = RandomGameLevel()
```

Finally, here is how you would use it in a case statement:

```
switch level {
case .Level(let levelValue):
    println("Level \(levelValue)")

case .TutorialLevel:
    println("Tutorial Level")

case .BossLevel:
    println("Boss Level")
}
```

---

**Update**

OK, it's not too hard to include the other values. I'll also put all of this into `GameLevel` to package it up better.

```
enum GameLevel {
    case Level(Int)
    case TutorialLevel, BossLevel

    static func Random() -> GameLevel {
        let maxGameLevel: UInt32 = 10 /* levels will be 0 through 9 */
        let otherGameLevels: UInt32 = 2 /* TutorialLevel and BossLevel */
        let levelValue = Int(arc4random_uniform(maxGameLevel + otherGameLevels))

        switch levelValue {
        case 10: return .TutorialLevel
        case 11: return .BossLevel
        default: return .Level(levelValue)
        }
    }
}
```

Then

```
let level = GameLevel.Random()
```

Not the cleanest, but it's a start.

Comment: your solution works fine with .Level(Int) cases but doesn't include `TutorialLevel, BossLevel` , and that's what I am struggling with

Answer (score 0):

```
enum GameLevel: CaseIterable {
    case Level(Int)
    case TutorialLevel, BossLevel
}

let level:GameLevel = GameLevel.allCases.randomElement()!
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: thank you Suraj Rao for for the corrections

Answer (score -2):

Why would you need it that way? :(

Assign numbers to your start and final levels and implement a function, which will return random in that range as Lvl(int)

Comment: Enum with raw type cannot have cases with arguments